# C# Converting Image to BLOB and Storing Result in Textbox

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, blob

I am working on (what should have been) a very simple project. It needs to

(1). Allow a user to select an image file then convert this into a format that can be stored in a database as a BLOB.

(2). Output the BLOB data into a textbox.

(3). The text that is output in the box needs to be capable of being stored into a database and then successfully converted back into an image (this conversion is handled elsewhere_.

This application here is just supposed to do the initial conversion (image to BLOB) so that the user can insert the image into an SQL database. However, whenever I run the program, it 'freezes' whenever I try opening the file. What am I doing wrong? Is there a more efficient approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Binary_Converter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private OpenFileDialog imageDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        private FileStream imageStream;
        public MainWindow()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
              imageDialog.InitialDirectory = "c://";
            imageDialog.Filter = "Image Files | *.jpg; *.gif; *.png";

            imageDialog.FileOk += imageDialog_FileOk;

        }



        private void UI_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {}




void imageDialog_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if((imageStream = (FileStream)imageDialog.OpenFile()) != null) {
        byte[] buffer;
    using(imageStream) {
     buffer = new byte[imageStream.Length];


        imageStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);    



    }
        foreach(byte i in buffer) {
            outputText.Text += buffer[i];
        }
    }

}

        private void addFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            imageDialog.ShowDialog();

        }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that your program freezes because you haven't converted the values to hexadecimal format. You are trying to output raw byte values, and it will "harm" your textbox as it will interpret it as a string with control characters. Hexadecimal format will be needed if you want to insert the value into the database.

```
 foreach(byte i in buffer) {
     outputText.Text += buffer[i];
 }

 outputText.Text = "0x"; // begin the string with 0x to tell that it is hexadecimal
 foreach(byte i in buffer) {
     outputText.Text += buffer[i].ToString("x2"); // convert each byte to hexadecimal form
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it to a textbox and then save it to the database.
If you have an `Image` or `Blob` column you save the `byte[]` directly.

This article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database) has more information about this.